# Get equivalence classes from OWL ontologies

Tags: java, python, rdf, owl, ontology

## UPDATE:

I've solved this problem. Using OWL API in Java I manage to retrieve all the axioms in the ontology, among which were all the Equivalent Classes I was looking for. As far as I know, there's no direct way to obtain unamed equivalent classes. This is the code I used:

```
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
o = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(hp);
Stream<OWLLogicalAxiom> logicalAxioms = o.logicalAxioms();
logicalAxioms.forEach(log::println);
```

## Question:

I have an ontology (Human Phenotype Ontology, or just 'hp') and I need to extract the classes from other ontologies referenced in my ontology inside the "owl:equivalentClass" tag. For instance: 
For the hp class "HP_0001561", I'd want extracted:

- BFO_0000051
- PATO_0000595
- RO_0000052
- UBERON_0000173
- RO_0002573
- PATO_0000460
- hp-logical-definitions-subq#during
- GO_0007565

Here's the class:

```
<!-- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0001561 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0001561">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Polyhydramnios</rdfs:label>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000051"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000595"/>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0000052"/>
                            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0000173"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002573"/>
                            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000460"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/hp/hp-logical-definitions-subq#during"/>
                            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0007565"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:intersectionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
```

I have tried several libraries to handle owl ontologies, but I can't find a way to do this. I've tried on Python, and I'm currently using OWL API on Java.

Comment: The `owl:equivalentClass` is perhaps not the relation that need to be used. `owl:sameAs` is refered to link concepts between different ontologies. [Documentation to owl:equivalentClass](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#equivalentClass-def)

Comment: Yes, that's very much true! But I am not looking for linking concepts here, I'm really looking for intersections between several ontologies, if that makes sense. I want to extract the information contained in the owl:equivalentClass tag.

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours.

Comment: About half of them are not classes.

Comment: BTW, visit the "Class Mappings" tab in [this page](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/HP/?p=classes&conceptid=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FHP_0001561&jump_to_nav=true#mappings).

Comment: Actually, the original question is correct. The entities in the HPO are classes, so EquivalenceAxioms is the correct construct, and this is indeed what is used in in OWL logical definitions.

Comment: Can you modify your question to indicate what is your end-goal? It sounds like you are not intending to get equivalent or close concepts in other ontologies and terminologies, e.g. UMLS, SNOMED, MP (if you were, then xrefs/mappings are the ways to do). It sounds like you are trying to break down the logical definition into its constituent parts, if you provided more info on why I can provide a more informative example.

Comment: Python -> [owlready](https://pythonhosted.org/Owlready2/) - or do you really want to handle RDF/XML by yourself?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you just parse it as XML, get all descendants of `owl:equivalentClass` and group their attributes. Then match all attributes that start with `http://purl.obolibrary.org/` and get the last path-item of the string?

Comment: I would recommend against use of XML parsers, unless this is for a quick one-off hack. There are multiple ways to structure RDF/XML, any code that uses XML as the abstraction layer has no guarantees of working with other equivalent serializations

Comment: @cmungall Yes, I am trying to break down the logical definitions, exactly

Comment: @BramVanroy I could do that yes, but I'm supposing I'd kinda lose the semantics, which I do not want, by the contrary... I could use an XML parser and do some posterior transformation, but I'd rather not.

Comment: What do you mean @StanislavKralin they're not classes?

Comment: For example, http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0000052 is a property (BTW, click the link). It seems you want to extract not equivalent classes, but "referenced entities", perhaps from other ontologies only. Then edit your question.

Comment: BTW, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZLzQ.png) is how Protege renders that class equivalence axiom.

Comment: Also it seems that [tag:owlready] is possibly [not](http://owlready.8326.n8.nabble.com/Accessing-the-axioms-and-axiom-closure-of-an-ontology-td217.html) what you need. And  there is the [tag:owl-api] tag on SO.

Comment: To do this in the OWLAPI, first query for equivalent classes and then call http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/HasClassesInSignature.html#getClassesInSignature-- - I can provide a detailed example later. But be warned that you are losing the structure of how these elements are related together

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!